# Returning a value to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I am new to jQuery. I have created a form where I hide some fields. I have created a function on the click of a button field. Here in this function definition I unhide the hidden fields one being my text field and another a button. I code that I use is:

```
finishOrder: function() {
    document.getElementById("create-pwd").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementById("finish-ok").style.display = "block" // this is my another button
    // do further processing
},
```

Now on the click of another button (please see the comment "this is my another button") I call another function like this:

```
FinishcheckPassword: function() {
    var pas = document.getElementById("pos-password")
    var user = new db.web.Model("res.users").get_func("read")(this.session.uid, ['password']).pipe(function(result) {
        if(pas.value == result.password){
            return true
    });
},
```

After the if condition returns true value, I want to the control to be transferred to the first function where I can do further processing. Is it possible, if yes how can this be achieved? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: just call it before returning true

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - I'm not sure that's good advice. Taking your recommendation further, you could easily end up with a maze of functions where one calls the next which calls the next which calls the next and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Sure, something like this:

```
$('#finish-ok').click(function(){
    if(FinishcheckPassword()){
        finishOrder();
    }
}
```

Of course, this is probably not exactly the right code for you. The fact that you are assigning all your functions with `:` rather than `=` suggests that they are inside of some larger object. Therefore, they'd have to be called like `myObject.finishOrder()`. But the general approach of what I wrote above will work.

As a couple side notes, you have tagged the question with jQuery and refer to it in your post, but there isn't actually a single line of jQuery in your code.

Comment: how can i use the above in my fuction. My button is defined like                              this:........       $('button#finish-ok', this.$element).click(_.bind(this.FinishcheckPassword, this));